# How to install packages per-user?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'd like to install programs without affecting other users on a box.  I can imagine a parallel install tree (`lib`, `bin`, `man`, etc.) in my user directory.

Can `apt-get` do that, or is there another technique that would work?

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way, IMO, is to compile from source.

Just specify a location with 'prefix'

```
./configure --prefix=/home/your_user/
make
make install
```

Often the hardest part of compiling is installing the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, which is what apt-get is for.  So you're saying there is no way with apt-get.  Okay.

Comment: Not with apt-get, but dependencies are not *that* hard to find. Either find them listed in the README, project home page, or if all else fails, the error messages when you compile (most error messages are dependencies). In Ubuntu most dependencies include a -dev package.